# Visual Studio 2015 C# New Line After Opening Curly Brace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, code-formatting

In Visual Studio 2015, under Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting, there are lots of great options for curly brace auto-formatting, but I don't see what I want.

Some people like this:

```
public static int MyFunc(){
    bla bla; 
}
```

Other people like this:

```
public static int MyFunc()
{
    bla bla; 
}
```

I want this:

```
public static int MyFunc()
{   bla bla; 
}
```

Anyone know how to get Visual Studio to format it this way? 
Thanks!

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to do that? You're going to get a lot of people cursing you if they need to maintain your code. One of the nice things about using editors such as Visual Studio is that it nudges people into consistent style, which makes life so much easier when you start moving between projects.

Comment: @Tone:  Good points, but it's pretty unlikely that anyone else will ever touch this code.  (Famous last words)?   I like style 2 (second example) better because it's much easier for me to keep track of nested blocks when the opening and closing curly braces are in the same column.   But, I like how style 1 (first example) save's a line.